# Django ListView set default queryset for get_queryset() method

Tags: django, listview, filter, default

I have a page with a list of posts and a search form to narrow down choices.

To use the form input in the ListView I changed the get_queryset() method:

```
from django.views import generic

def is_valid_queryparam(param):
    return param != '' and param is not None

class PostsListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Posts

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Posts.objects.all()

        # get parameters from URL, for example
        # http://localhost:8000/list/title_contains=example&username_contains=example
        title_contains_query = self.request.GET.get('title_contains')
        username_contains_query = self.request.GET.get('username_contains')

        # filter queryset based on form inputs
        if is_valid_queryparam(title_contains_query):
            qs = qs.filter(title__icontains=title_contains_query)
        if is_valid_queryparam(username_contains_query):
            qs = qs.filter(author__username__icontains=username_contains_query)

        # then return the filtered queryset
        return(qs)
```

template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

<div class="form-section">
  <form method="GET" action=".">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-6">
          {{ form.title|as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-6">
          {{ form.username|as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

{% for post in object_list %}
<div>
  <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
  <h3>{{ post.author }}</h3>
  <p> {{ post.content }}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

The search form is working nicely but the problem is that now when I first open the page with the list of posts my list view lists nothing until I fill out the search form and click submit.

I would like to display all posts on the page by default before filling out the search form to search for specific posts.

What is the best way to do this?

Update: added example of how queryset is processed with URL parameters

Comment: Can you give a sample `get_queryset` on how you process the URL parameters?

Comment: I don't understand, you're talking about a form, but showing us only a list view. That list view by the way is correctly fetching all posts (you don't even need to override `get_queryset()`, `all()` is the default anyway) so if in your template you loop through `object_list` (`{% for post in object_list %}`) you should see all the posts.

Comment: @Wilem Thanks. I added an example of how the URL parameters are processed. The form is not the issue. It is correctly fetching the URL parameters.

Comment: @ dirkgroten: Yes, in my template I loop through `{% for post in object_list %}`, but I only get a list of all posts if I submit an empty form. I want the list of all posts to be there without having to click submit on the form.